# MacBook Pro 13'' mid-2012 16 GB RAM upgrade effect

Tags: macbook-pro

I did upgrade my MacBook 13’’ mid-2012 to 16 GB RAM. Now when opening the lid after the computer slept for about an hour or so, I get a semi-transparent screen with a stepped progressive bar for approximately 2 minutes after that everything seems ok. No other changes are made to the computer. What is the reason?

Comment: Define "stepped progressive bar" or ad a pic to your question. Note that a Mac with more RAM will come out of hibernation more slowly because there is more RAM to be read from disk.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Do You think SSD upgrade ill fix it?

Comment: Well SSDs are *faster* and while it is impossible to really tell, it *should*

Comment: If your MPB is running a spinning disk (5400-rpm SATA) which was the original build, (SSDs were an option,) the hibernation delay is the most likely cause.

Comment: I think that I saw strange things like this when I did the same upgrade but I don't see it anymore.  "If it works, don't fix it."